# beamerposter subfigure

Tags: beamer, subfloats, beamerposter

I am making a poster with beamerposter and it is treating all my subfigures as part of a single figure, lettering them (a), (b), ..., (q), even though I very clearly \end{figure} several times, which should reset the count.  I want each \begin{figure} ... \end{figure} block to have its own subfigure lettering, starting from (a).  I copied the figures over directly from a .tex article where they are lettered appropriately.  What am I doing wrong?

This is a minimal working example:

```
   \documentclass[serif,mathserif,final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Jorstad}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,pxfonts,eulervm,xspace}
\usepackage{floatflt,subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=A0,debug]{beamerposter}

%-- Header and footer information ----------------------------------
\newcommand{\footleft}{}
\newcommand{\footright}{}
\title{a}
\author{a}
\institute{a}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------


%-- Main Document --------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{columns}[t]

%-- Column 1 ---------------------------------------------------
\begin{column}{0.24\linewidth}

    %-- Block 1-2
    \begin{block}{Section 1}

    \begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{center}
    \subfigure[$I_1$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_scream_1.png} \label{BA_exp_1}}
    \subfigure[$I_2$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_scream_2.png} \label{BA_exp_2}}
    \subfigure[$w$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_scream_3.png} \label{BA_exp_3}}
    \subfigure[$I_2^w$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_scream_4.png} \label{BA_exp_4}}  \\
    \subfigure[$I_1$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_lighting_1.png} \label{BA_lgt_1}}
    \subfigure[$I_2$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_lighting_2.png} \label{BA_lgt_2}}
    \subfigure[$w$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_lighting_3.png} \label{BA_lgt_3}}
    \subfigure[$I_2^w$] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/BA_lighting_4.png} \label{BA_lgt_4}}
    \label{BA_failures}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

\end{block}
\end{column}%1



%-- Column 2 ---------------------------------------------------
\begin{column}{0.41\linewidth}

        \begin{block}{Section 2}

        \begin{figure}[t]  %hp
        \begin{center}
        \subfigure[] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/face51.png} }
        \subfigure[] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/face51_expressions.png} }
        \subfigure[] {\includegraphics[height=2in]{pics/face51_lightings.png} }
        \end{center}
        \end{figure}


\end{block}

\end{column}%3

\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Ideally I want each figure to reset the subfigure captions starting from (a) alternately removing the letters while keeping the caption would be OK.

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating your problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, I've edited the question a little bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the now obsolete package `subfigure`; you should use `subcaption` instead.

The reason why the numbering for the subfigures does not reset is because you are not using a caption for the figures (and the `subfigure` counter resets every time the `figure` counter is incremented, which wont happen without a caption). A quick fix would be to add

```
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
```

just before each new group of figures to manually restart the counter (or to add
in the preamble

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{}
```

to suppress the numbering for the subfigures, as you also propose in your question).

An automatic solution can be obtained by using a `\caption` for the figures; if you want to suppress the name `Figure` and the label separator `:` that the use of `\caption` causes, then one possibility is to use in the preamble

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{mystyle}{name=none}
\captionsetup[figure]{style=mystyle}
\usepackage{floatflt,subfigure}
```

and to write `\caption{}` inside each `figure` environment.

Comment: @carlosdc: I discovered the real reason for the problem. I updated my answer, providing one possible correct and automatic solution.