# How to add subfigures in a poster?

Tags: subfloats, a0poster

I am making a scientific poster in Latex. The code is working fine if I am working with single figures but as soon as I am adding subfigures (figures side by side), I am getting several errors at once. The code to include subfigures is correct since I verified it by taking it in an a4 sheet only. The Latex code I am using is as follows

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0]{sciposter}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    %\usepackage{subfig}
   \usepackage{array}
   \usepackage{braket}
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
   \usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
%\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{sectionbox}


\renewcommand{\titlesize}{\Huge}
\renewcommand{\authorsize}{\Large}
\renewcommand{\instsize}{\large}

\title{title}
\author{name}
\institute{nameinst}
\email{jvlfvj} 

\leftlogo[1]{logo.jpg}
\conference{Open Poster Presentation}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\fontpointsize}{15pt}

\begin{multicols}{3}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ers.png}
 \caption{diagram}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{uvw.eps}
   \caption{a}
   \end{subfigure}%
   \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
   \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{xyz.eps}
  \caption{b}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{abc.eps}
  \caption{c}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{fig}
  \end{figure}

  \end{multicols}

  \end{document}
```

I have tried various combinations of the packages given in preamble. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: No floats inside multicols. There are lots of ways to arrange images on a poster that do not involve figures, subfigures or columns.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I got errors only after adding subfigures. I didn't get any when I compiled with ers.png (see code).

Comment: You should have gotten a warning.  And the figures should have been delayed until after \end{multicols}.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry, but I didn't understand what you meant by "the figures should have been delayed until after \end{multicols}". I got a few warnings but the output was perfect. Also, I have just shown a part of the code. There are equations and text also in between the figures. The poster has three columns and I would like to add figures and subfigures in the poster. It would be of great help if you can elaborate your answer.

Comment: As an alternative, if something in `sciposter` just won't work, there's also [`beamerposter`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) ([external homepage](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php)). It can do subfigures with the `subcaption` package, as shown in [beamerposter subfigure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20856/beamerposter-subfigure).

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks for your comment. I am able to add subfigures using beamerposter templates. The default preamble of beamerposter is not using any graphicx package. Maybe its included in some other package. So when I added pdftex graphicx package, it showed option clash for package graphicx error. But when I removed it from the preamble, it was working fine. Still I am new to Latex, I don't know if I will be able to customize it to my needs.

Comment: I noticed in the manual that the sciposter redefines the figure environment to no longer be a float.  OTOH, it also says not to load the subfigure package.

Comment: I'm sure the beamer document class that beamerposter automatically includes `graphicx`. And adding engine-specific options like `pdftex` to `graphicx` hasn't been required for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

"When all else fails, read the manual."  Sciposter redefines the figure environment, \caption and \subfigure.  However, \subfigure is implemented as a tabular, not a minipage.  Also, it uses subfig instead of subfigure as a counter, but \captionof doesn't know what to do with subfig.

So to get the captions to work right, I went back to figure and caption, but used minipage and created \subcaption for subfigures.

Just for fun, I also created a subfigure environment.  When not creating a list of figures, it's probably the most trivial environment in existence.

[image: cropped poster]

```
\documentclass[portrait,a0]{sciposter}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example images

\newcommand{\subcaption}[1]% %1 = text
{\refstepcounter{subfig}%
\par\vskip\abovecaptionskip
\centerline{\textbf{(\alph{subfig})} #1}%
\vskip\belowcaptionskip\par}

% create subfigure environment
\def\subfigure{\let\oldcaption=\caption
\let\caption=\subcaption
\minipage}
\def\endsubfigure{\endminipage
\let\caption=\oldcaption}

\renewcommand{\titlesize}{\Huge}
\renewcommand{\authorsize}{\Large}
\renewcommand{\instsize}{\large}

\leftlogo[1]{example-image}
\conference{Open Poster Presentation}

\title{title}
\author{name}
\institute{nameinst}
\email{jvlfvj} 

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\renewcommand{\fontpointsize}{15pt}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
 \caption{diagram}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{a}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil
 \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{b}
 \end{subfigure}\hfil
 \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{c}
 \end{subfigure}%
  \caption{fig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The title and the logo should be at top and outside the columns. The figures and subfigures are distributed in the three columns in the main body of the poster. I will try this out. But you have not used columns in your code. As you already mentioned, is it really not possible to use subfigures in multicols in sciposter ?

Comment: If you had put text inside the multicols, all of the text would have printed before the first figure.  Subfigures do some nasty things so that they they will show up in the list of figures AFTER the figure caption, even if the figure caption is expanded later.  Anyway, if you don't want a list of figures or use figure numbers, you can replace \captionof with plain old centered text.

Comment: I tried using your code but in multicols environment, the figures are appearing in columns and not side by side. I also tried a0poster but in that I got a warning that floats are not allowed in multicols environment.