# Fine-tuning the subfig labels

Tags: floats, hyperref, cross-referencing, subfloats

I have a large document (in the `report` class) with a bunch of subfigures, and I'm currently in the middle of a migration from the (apparently deprecated) `subfigure` package to `subfig`, but I'm having trouble getting the finer details to work well. Specifically:

- I want normal references of the form `\ref{fig}` to print out in the format 1.1(a) (i.e. chapter, figure, subfigure, with parenthesis around the latter).
- I want a `\subref`-type command that allows me to access the (a) part of that identifier.
- I also want a `\subref*`-style caller that allows me to just get the a on its own, without the brackets (or, alternatively, allow me to reference multiple parts in one go, i.e. Figure 1.1(b-d) or (e,f), directly).

I am aware of [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16291/adding-parentheses-around-subfig-references), but the methods there only allow for two of the three goals, as they either take over `\subref*` for what `\subref` does above, or they pollute the `\thesubfigure` counter.

I'm OK with a migration that can be done with a search-and-replace (like e.g. changing `\subfigure[...]{...}` to `\subfloat[...]{...}`, but I'm a bit more wary of changes that require changing that to a full environment-based solution. Also, any solutions need to play well with `hyperref`.

I should also say that I find it frustrating that 'deprecated' packages are superseded by others that are nowhere near flexible enough and that break backwards compatibility in severe ways.

Comment: If you are going to migrate to a more current package, I would recommend subcaption (although personally I use minipages and format my own subcaptions).  You can always create you own \subfig macro.  They are pretty trivial to create.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287919/cls-file-not-compiling-subfigure/287941?s=1|1.0744#287941 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235284/how-to-add-subfigures-in-a-poster/235287?s=2|0.5651#235287